# How to eliminate implications with quantifiers

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm reading some stuffs on the conversion of a FOL sentence to CNF form.
However, I'm stuck with this problem: why should this

$$\forall x [\forall y Animal(y) \Rightarrow Loves(x,y)] \Rightarrow [\exists y Loves(y,x)]$$

be equal to this
$$\forall x [\neg \forall y \neg Animal(y) \lor  Loves(x,y)] \lor [\exists y Loves(y,x)]$$

? I know that $\alpha \Rightarrow \beta$ is equivalent to $\neg \alpha \lor \beta$, but I can't figure out how this equivalence was applied at the first sentence.

---

### EDIT

Ok, it seems that Wikipedia has the same example, but a different (I think) soultion at [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Converting_from_first-order_logic). The step by step simplification looks like this.

$$\forall x [\forall y Animal(y) \Rightarrow Loves(x,y)] \Rightarrow [\exists y Loves(y,x)]$$
$$\forall x [\forall y \neg Animal(y) \lor Loves(x,y)] \Rightarrow [\exists y Loves(y,x)]$$
$$\forall x \neg[\forall y \neg Animal(y) \lor Loves(x,y)] \lor [\exists y Loves(y,x)]$$

Then, it continues moving the $\neg$ inward in this way.
$$\forall x [\exists y \neg (\neg Animal(y) \lor Loves(x,y))] \lor [\exists y Loves(y,x)]$$
but it seems quite different from the result of my example. So, is the formula shown on my book wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to see what they did if you add some extra brackets. Note that:
\begin{align*}
&\forall x \, \left[ \forall y \, [\textsf{Animal}(y) \to \textsf{Loves}(x, y)] \to \exists y \, \textsf{Loves}(y, x) \right] \\
&\equiv \forall x \, \left[ \forall y \, [\neg \textsf{Animal}(y) \lor \textsf{Loves}(x, y)] \to \exists y \, \textsf{Loves}(y, x) \right] \\
&\equiv \forall x \, \left[\neg \forall y \, [\neg \textsf{Animal}(y) \lor \textsf{Loves}(x, y)] \lor \exists y \, \textsf{Loves}(y, x) \right] \\
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks both to you and @MauroALLEGRANZA, both of you answered the question in the same moment. So, the parentesis shown on the first sentence of my question was wrong (or probably misleading)? What about the edited part? Wikipedia solution seems to be different (at least for a newbie like me)

Comment: Wikipedia's solution is exactly what I have. Yes, the parentheses in your first sentence were a bit misleading.

Comment: Indeed, now that I look a little bit closer to both, it seems that they are actually equal. I think I have to work on parentheses :)

Answer (score 2):

First, we have to "restore" the missing parentheses :

> ∀x[∀y(Animal(y)⇒Loves(x,y)) ⇒ ∃yLoves(y,x)]

then apply the "transformtion to the "inner" ⇒ :

> ∀x[∀y(¬ Animal(y) ∨ Loves(x,y)) ⇒ ∃yLoves(y,x)]

and then to the "outer" one :

> > ∀x[¬∀y(¬ Animal(y) ∨ Loves(x,y)) ∨ ∃yLoves(y,x)].